# Need help making button with js then linking it to a function and css code

Tags: javascript, css, html, code-injection

I need am essentially making a piece of code that will inject my own code onto the webpage.

Due to me being limited on my ipad I am using bookmarklets so here it is:

I am using this code to call on a js file that will create the button

```
    javascript: (function () { 
        var jsCode = document.createElement('script'); 
        jsCode.setAttribute('src', 'http://path/to/external/file.js');                  
        document.body.appendChild(jsCode); 
     }());
```

The button I want to make will need to be created with the code shown below:

```
    <button id=“supermoneybutton” onclick=“moneyget()”>get money</button>
```

Then I need to add a link to an external css file.

I have the file for the css, I just need help making the js work, the injection code already works it just shows my method for injection.

Comment: HTML does not recognize `“smartquotes”`. You should use a proper IDE or at least a plain text editor for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS code that dynamically creates the button, you should add the event handler there too:

```
(function () {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.id = 'supermoneybutton';
    button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // Do Stuff
        moneyget();
    });
    document.body.appendChild(button);

    // Add CSS File
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = '/path/to/cssfile';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    var linkRef = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
    linkRef.parentNode.insertBefore(link, linkRef);
})();
```

Comment: I also need something tat will run that, could I take it out of the function to make it run when I create it? Also, how would I create a css element

Comment: Yes, you can make it into an IIFE and it will run on page load. Updated answer to make it auto invoked and how to add css link.

Comment: What is an iife, also, this will be put in after the page loads